# How to find the duplicate words in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

These are table information.

```
CREATE TABLE actor(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT actor_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE movie(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR2(100),
yr NUMBER(4,0),
score NUMBER,
votes INTEGER,
director VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT movie_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE casting(
movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
actor_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
ord INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT casting_PK PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id),
CONSTRAINT casting_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(id),
CONSTRAINT casting_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES actor(id));
```

How do I find the top 5 popular words used as the first word in a movie title? 
(Exclude ‘A’, ‘An’, ‘The’ and ‘I’). 
List the words by their number of appearances from high to low. You can
ignore movie titles with only one word.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried?  This looks to be a string manipulation to replace 'A ' 'An ' 'The ' and 'I ' with empty string then find the first space after that in the next word and group by it and count order count descending  or one could use regular expressions to remove the unneeded words; or you could split on spaces and eliminate the words in a where clause... lots of options.

Comment: What does "exclude certain words" mean? Ignore the title completely or use the first other word?

Answer (score 0):

This simple approach will look for the first occurrence of blank (only in titles with blanks). It will order it in descending order by number of occurrences discarding the list ('A', 'An', 'The', 'I')

```
with words AS (
    SELECT
        substr(m.title, 1, instr(m.title, ' ')) AS firstword,
        COUNT(*) AS counter
    FROM
        movie m
    WHERE
        instr(m.title, ' ') > 0
    GROUP BY
        substr(m.title, 1, instr(m.title, ' '))
)
SELECT
    w.firstword,
    w.counter
FROM
    words w
where UPPER(w.firstword) not in ('A', 'AN', 'THE', 'I')
ORDER BY
    w.counter DESC
```

If you want it case insensitive:

```
with words AS (
    SELECT
        UPPER(substr(m.title, 1, instr(m.title, ' '))) AS firstword,
        COUNT(*) AS counter
    FROM
        movie m
    WHERE
        instr(m.title, ' ') > 0
    GROUP BY
        UPPER(substr(m.title, 1, instr(m.title, ' ')))
)
SELECT
    w.firstword,
    w.counter
FROM
    words w
where w.firstword not in ('A', 'AN', 'THE', 'I')
ORDER BY
    w.counter DESC
```

Comment: the result returns 'a', 'an', 'the', 'i'.

Comment: @Shawn Oracle is case sensitive. Try with upper(). I've edited my answer